# How to (Un)Focus YouTube's Video Element

Tags: javascript, html, dart, dom, youtube

> This question comes from me trying to develop a  [browser extension to enhance YouTube's keyboard navigation](https://github.com/FanaroEngineering/youtube_kbd_nav).

### 1. The Context

Usually, it's not at all clear to me when the web page has the focus on YouTube's `video` player element or when the focus is on the page's body instead. If the focus is on the `video` element, then the arrow keys will control the video; otherwise, if the focus is on the page's body itself, the arrow keys will control scrolling.

I would like to add a shortcut to (de)activate the focus on the `video` element. How do I do that?

### 2. What I've Tried

Simply using `document.querySelector('video').focus()` or `document.activeElement.blur()` isn't working for me. Neither is something like `document.activeElement.setAttribute('disabled', 'true')`...

### 3. Other Info

Ideally, since, visually, it isn't clear to the user where the focus is usually, I would like to add some CSS border decoration later on, but I think that will be simple once the previous challenge is worked out.

> Quite frankly, why the hell doesn't YouTube have all this already? It seems lazy on their part...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. One Possible Solution

Try changing focus on the `div` `#movie_player` element instead:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (evt) => {
  if (evt.key === 'v') {
    const player = document.querySelector('#movie_player');

    document.activeElement.id === 'movie_player'
      ? player.blur()
      : player.focus();

    console.log('Active Element:', document.activeElement);
  }
});
```

### 2. Bonus: The Dart Version of the Solution Above

Or, since you've been using Dart:

```dart
document.onKeyDown.listen((KeyboardEvent keyboardEvent) {
  switch (keyboardEvent.key) {
    case 'v':
      final Element player = document.querySelector('#movie_player');

      document.activeElement.id == 'movie_player' 
          ? player.blur() 
          : player.focus();

      print('Active Element: ${document.activeElement}');

      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: I'll take a look at it today or tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: It's apparently working, even in Dart. I really don't understand why it wasn't working for me because what I was trying was very simple to what you did, but, anyway, it doesn't matter anymore. Thanks a lot!